# Excel 2013 Text Replace

Tags: excel, replace

I want to change the text in multiple cells in a column to say something else in a different column.  For example, if my column is named "Food" and I have multiple entries of "apple", "banana", "orange" etc.  How can I find all the fruits and name it "Fruit" in a different column but same row?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"banana","fruit"),"orange","fruit"),"apple","fruit")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the code:

```
Public Function MultiSub(rSource As Range, rXlate As Range) As String
    Dim s As String

    s = rSource.Text

    xlate = rXlate

    For i = LBound(xlate, 1) To UBound(xlate, 1)
        s = Replace(s, xlate(i, 1), xlate(i, 2))
    Next i

    MultiSub = s
End Function
```

The first argument is the source cell and the second argement is the translate table:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Substitute, I couldn't remember.  So I have to type each word separately of can I list a range.  I have thousands of names I need to substitute in to dozens of other names.

Comment: @MikeO'Neill  You you want is easy with ***VBA*** , are you O.K. with that approach ??

Comment: @MikeO'Neill  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @MikeO'Neill  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula based solution try this.

Name the range with list of fruits as "Fruit".

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Fruit,0)),A1,"Fruit")
```